# Is it possible to call a variable from string input

Tags: c#

I have five Labels in my form.

The names of the label are the following.

```
1) labelTeam1Name.Text
1) labelTeam2Name.Text
3) labelTeam3Name.Text
4) labelTeam4Name.Text
5) labelTeam5Name.Text
```

now I want to run a loop and get the text values of the label

```
for( int i = 1; i < 6; i++ )
{
    string str = labelTeam(i)Name.Text  // Get the values based on the input i

}
```

I can definitely fill these values in an array or list and then call them in the loop.

is it possible to do something like this labelTeam(i)Name.Text?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the Controls.Find() method:

```
for( int i = 1; i < 6; i++ )
{
    string str = ((Label)Controls.Find("labelTeam" + i + "Name",true)[0]).Text  // Get the values based on the input i

}
```

Comment: In that case, you can write `$"labelTeam{i}Name"`, instead of `"labelTeam" + i + "Name"`.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `Controls` and [`OfType`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.oftype?view=netframework-4.8)

> Filters the elements of an IEnumerable based on a specified type.

```
var results = Controls.OfType<Label>().Select(x => x.Text);
```

or

```
foreach (var ctrl in Controls.OfType<Label>())
{
    //var str = ctrl.Text;    
}
```

if you need to base this on the name, you could use `Find` or

```
var labels = Controls.OfType<Label>().ToList();

for (int i = 0; i < labels.Count(); i++)
{
   var label = labels.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Name == $"blerp{i}derp");

   if (label != null)
   {

   }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a Label array.

```
System.Windows.Forms.Label[] Labels = new System.Windows.Forms.Label[5];

Labels[0] = labelTeam1Name;

Labels[1] = labelTeam2Name;

Labels[2] = labelTeam3Name;

Labels[3] = labelTeam4Name;

Labels[4] = labelTeam5Name;

for( int i = 0; i < Labels.Lenth; i++ )
{
    string str = Labels[i].Text; 
}
```